# How to use applymap, lambda and dataframe together to filter / modify dataframe in python?

Tags: python, function, pandas, lambda

So I 'm trying to figure it out how to replace `NaN` in `pd.DataFrame` .. ?
Here in the example I created the 3x3 dataframe, having value in `df[1][2] = 'a'` and the rest are `NaN`

My understanding is that I can use `if` with in `lambda` and do something below. But the result was not what I expected, it overwrite `'a'`. I still want `'a'` to remain as it is and only change to `'o'` where is `NaN` ... Any recommendation would be appreciated.

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,3),columns=range(0,3))
df[1][2] = 'a'
f = lambda x: 'o' if np.nan else x
df.applymap(f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.nan` does not really return the value you are expecting, in order to create a valid predicate, you can use `pd.isnull`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,3),columns=range(0,3))
df[1][2] = 'a'
f = lambda x: 'o' if pd.isnull(x) else x
df.applymap(f)

#   0   1   2
#0  o   o   o
#1  o   o   o
#2  o   a   o
```

To see why it is happening, you can convert `np.nan` to boolean:

```
bool(np.nan)
# True
```

So it is always returning true value thus all values in the data frame will be replaced by `o`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `apply`, you could use `fillna`.

```
df.fillna('o')
```

For more information about [Working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html). You could also use `apply` with `pd.isnull()` as mentaioned in @Psidom answer. But in this case, you should really use the built-in function `fillna`.